Interpretation of algebraic-geometric language into differential-geometric language
I want to know how to interpret a proposition stated by algebraic geometry language in a differential geometry way.
For example, roughly speaking, I think schemes corresponds to complex manifolds, morphisms corresponds to holomorphic maps. And I guess the certain properties of morphisms, such as finite, regular, proper also have the differential-geometric interpretation. Is there a dictionary or any notes about this?

There are versions of Jean Pierre Serre’s GAGA that have been simplified so you can probably follow, that would be better than anything you could get here. Modern algebraic geometry is described in a way that it applies to problems in number theory. There is a lot of generalization that makes it hard to see how it connects to differential geometry.
An Affine scheme is an Apparatus built over the topological space that parametrizes the prime ideals of a finitely generated commutative algebra. More specifically, if $A$ is a finitely generated commutative algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ then $Spec(A)$ is the set of prime ideals of $A$ in the Zariski topology. If $s\in A$ then the  principal open subset determined by $A$ is $$D(s)=\{\mathfrak{p}\in Spec(A)|s\not \in \mathfrak{p}\}.$$ The principal open subsets are a basis for the Zariski topology.  The closure of a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ in the Zariski topology is all prime ideals containing $\mathfrak{p}$ . The maximal spectrum
$Max Spec(A)$ is the set of maximal ideals these are exactly the closed points of $Spec(A)$.   In the differential geometric setting the maximal spectrum would be the points of the manifold. A feature of algebraic geometry is that a space is actually a category where the morphisms are given by inclusion. That's right in algebraic geometry you treat subspaces of the variety on the same footing as it's points.  The condition that the algebra is finitely generated means that each element of the space is made up of points.  It also means that $Spec(A)$ is compact.
You want the morphisms between varieties to be induced by homomorphisms between the algebras.  The inverse image of a maximal ideal ( point) is not necessarily a maximal ideal, but the inverse image of a prime ideal is prime.   If $f:A\rightarrow B$ is an algebra homomorphism then
$$ f^*:Spec(B)\rightarrow Spec(A)$$ defined by $$f^*(\mathfrak{p})=f^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$$ is a continuous mapping.
There is more to the definition of an affine scheme. You also need to have the structure sheaf. The structure sheaf tells you what admissible functions are. In the differential geometry setting these would be holomorphic functions. The word sheaf means you know what the functions assigned to open sets are, you can paste together functions that agree on the overlap of open sets, and you can tell if a function is zero by checking that it is zero for all the open sets in an open cover of the space. If $X=Spec(A)$  the structure sheaf is denoted $\mathcal{O}_X$.
A scheme is the result of gluing together affine schemes. You denote it by the pair $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$.  Morphisms of schemes take some getting used to.  A morphism is a pair consiting of a continuous map of topological spaces and then an ambiguously defined morphism of sheaves. I say ambiguous because there are two ways of defining the morphism and they seem to have pretty equal standing. My definition of structure sheaf is so hands off, that I really can't describe this part of the morphism to you.
In general the sheaf concept is about organizing localizations of modules. A famous theorem of Serre relates finitely generated projective modules over an algebra to the global sections of a vector bundle over it's spectrum.
Here is the lexicon.  A manifold is the closed points of the scheme, coordinate patches are affine schemes, the smooth mappings are morphisms of schemes, a vector bundle corresponds to a finitely generated  projective module over the algebra of smooth functions.
The point of Serre’s GAGA is to understand the analogy carefully so that you can prove theorems in algebraic geometry using differential geometric techniques.

The maximal spectrum is not closed in the spectrum.

I deleted that sentence.
